# Sliding sidebar position calculations not correct

Tags: jquery, sidebar, sticky

I'm building a Follow or Sticky sidebar in jQuery for a website I'm working on.

[Here's a link to the site with the sidebar.](http://www.lawmentorship.com/practice-areas/)

You can see it's behavior is very strange.  I'm trying to follow this guide and add a stop function once it gets to the bottom:

http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/

When the user scrolls down, I want the sidebar to remain at the top with a 32px top-padding, and when a user scrolls to the bottom, I want the sidebar to stop with a 32px bottom-padding at the top of the footer.  I'm confused about the variables and the math behind it, in my head it makes sense, but maybe I need someone else to take a look at it.

Anyways, here's the jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        $footer    = $("footer"), // use your footer ID here
        foffset    = $footer.offset(),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        threshold  = foffset.top - $sidebar.height(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > threshold) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: threshold
            });
        } else if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $sidebar.height() - offset.top + topPadding
            }, 400);
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            }, 400);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And the CSS for the sidebar id:

```
#sidebar { 
  position: fixed !important; 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to include padding your calculation:

```
threshold  = foffset.top - $sidebar.outerHeight(),
```